# How to shorten the python code?

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

I'm writing a program that takes a number from input (call it x), loops from 0 to (x - 1) (let's call our iterator y) and prints \$y^x+x\$ for each y.

After the loop, it then prints "SUM: N" (without a newline) where the N is the sum of the all of the previously printed values.

How can I make the code I already have shorter?

Code (Python 3, 98 bytes):

```python
E=print
A=int(input())
B=[]
for D in range(A):C=D**A+A;B.append(C);E(C)
E(end='SUM: '+str(sum(B)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39W2oCgzr4TL0RZIamTmFZSWaGhqcjnZRsdypeUXKbgoZOYpFCXmpadqOGpaOdu6aGk5ajtaO@klFhSk5qVoOGtauwIJLlcNIM9WPTjU10pBXbu4pEijuDRXw0lTU/P/fzMA)

Comment: Could whoever VTC'd this clarify why they think it is unclear? OP has given a fairly good description of what is expected, and has provided code to be golfed.

Comment: Normally I'd be worried about posts that just ask "HOW DO FIX?" but this seems like a pretty good example of a Python Code to golf, And is, imo, worth keeping up as both a question and a tips question.

Comment: Is it valid to terminate with error by taking an `input` that doesn't exist? If so, you can use `input` to print without a newline for the ending sum.

Comment: @xnor no it's not valid to end with input.

Comment: You said "loops from 0 to x", but your code is "loops from 0 to (x-1)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## My attempt, <s>86</s> 79 bytes

```python
E=print
A=int(input())
E(end='SUM: %d'%sum(E(C:=D**A+A)or C for D in range(A)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/39W2oCgzr4TL0RZIamTmFZSWaGhqcrlqpOal2KoHh/paKaimqKsWl@ZquGo4W9m6aGk5ajtq5hcpOCukAUkXhcw8haLEvPRUDUdNTc3//80A)

Thanks to dingledooper for shaving off 7 bytes by removing the need for `B`.

We embed the assignment in a list comprehension for -9 bytes. `print` returns a falsy value, so `E(C:=D**A+A)or C` returns `C` which is collected into the generator `E(C:=D**A+A)or C for D in range(A)` that is passed to `sum`.

We also format the output with a `%d` to save bytes off `str`.

Comment: Ah well done! It looks like this method can be further reduced to [79 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/39W2oCgzr4TL0RZIamTmFZSWaGhqcrlqpOal2KoHh/paKaimqKsWl@ZquGo4W9m6aGk5ajtq5hcpOCukAUkXhcw8haLEvPRUDUdNTc3//80A).

Comment: @dingledooper That's quite neat, thanks!

Comment: +1. Accepted; Shortest bytes possible in the CGCC answer.

Answer (score 11):

Just a different approach to reduce your code to 86 bytes. You don't need to rename the `print` function. The only thing you need is to first compute all the values and only then print them:

```
A=int(input())
B=[D**A+A for D in range(A)]
print(*B,f'SUM: {sum(B)}',sep='\n',end='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39E2M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTy8k22kVLy1HbUSEtv0jBRSEzT6EoMS89VcNRM5aroAikVstJJ009ONTXSqG6uDRXw0mzVl2nOLXAVj0mT10nNS/FVl1d8/9/UwA)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Answer (score 5):

Doing it in a list comprehension is a waste of time, it seems, mainly since you have to have a separate print statement for the final sum (due to the no-newline limit).

97 bytes:

```python
E=print
f=lambda x:[E(g:=i**x+x)or g for i in range(x)]
E(end='SUM: '+str(sum(f(int(input())))))
```

Instead, there's a couple changes I noted.

```python
E=print
A=int(input())
B=[]
for D in range(A):C=D**A+A;B.append(C);E(C)
E(end='SUM: '+str(sum(B)))
```

First, you can do `B+=[C]` instead of `B.append(C)`. That loses 5 bytes for 93. But we can also just use B as an integer and add - that saves us from having to do a sum later, so we can shave off a total of 11 for a total of 85.

```python
E=print
A=int(input())
B=0
for D in range(A):C=D**A+A;B+=C;E(C)
E(end='SUM: '+str(B))
```

We can then do an inline variable assignment when printing `D**A+A` to save bytes as well, from `C=D**A+A;B+=C;E(C)` to `E(G:=D**A+A);B+=G`. This saves one byte, for 84 bytes.

```python
E=print
A=int(input())
B=0
for D in range(A):E(G:=D**A+A);B+=G
E(end='SUM: '+str(B))
```

Lastly, calling `str` is long and unwieldy. There's no backticks to call `repr` like in Python 2, but we can just use autocasting print arguments to do it anyway. From `E(end='SUM: '+str(B))` to just `E('SUM: ',B,end='')`. We add two single quotes and a comma, but lose out on 5 bytes from the `str()`, for a total of -2 and a final byte count of 83.

```python
E=print
B=0
A=int(input())
for D in range(A):E(G:=D**A+A);B+=G
E('SUM: ',B,end='')
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding all the terms to a list and calling `sum`, it's a lot shorter to keep a running total. This gets the solution down to 85 bytes:

```py
E=print
A=int(input())
S=0
for D in range(A):C=D**A+A;S+=C;E(C)
E(end='SUM: '+str(S))
```

From here, two more optimizations can be made. The first is to make use of f-strings, saving three bytes. The second is to convert the for loop to a while loop, which saves another byte. With this we get an 81-byte solution:

```py
E=print
A=int(input())
S=D=0
while D<A:C=D**A+A;S+=C;E(C);D+=1
E(end=f'SUM: {S}')
```

For Python >=3.8, you can also utilize the walrus operator to save 1 more byte.

```py
E=print
A=int(input())
S=D=0
while D<A:E(C:=D**A+A);S+=C;D+=1
E(end=f'SUM: {S}')
```