# In as few bytes as possible in t-sql, return 100 rows containing the phrase 'Have a great Christmas'

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, tips, sql

In as few bytes as possible in t-sql, return 100 rows containing the phrase 'Have a great Christmas'

92 (I think) to beat :D

```
CREATE TABLE #(m char(99))
GO
INSERT # SELECT'Have a great Christmas'
GO 100
SELECT * FROM #
```

Previous best effort was:

```
WITH t(m,r)AS(SELECT'Have a great Christmas',1 UNION ALL SELECT m,r+1 FROM t WHERE r<100)SELECT m FROM t;
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! By the way, why is the scoring in characters instead of the site default of bytes?

Comment: If you posted your 96 byte code here, you could also make this a [tag:tips] question.

Comment: Ok cool, as an answer or comment?

Comment: For a language-specific tips question, you can put the code in the body of the question, like [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/237859/16766).

Comment: What version of TSQL are you looking for?

Comment: Any really, just for fun. Loving the creativity

Answer (score 4):

## SQL Server (tested on 2016) - <strike>82</strike> 78 bytes

```
SELECT TOP 100*FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE('Have a great Christmas!',100),'!')
```

### SQL Server (tested on 2016) - <strike>88</strike> 87 bytes (Old Solution)

```
WITH N(a)AS(SELECT'Have a great Christmas'UNION ALL SELECT*FROM N)SELECT TOP 100*FROM N
```

Of course, on a sql instance with existing objects, you can come up with some... hackier solutions.

For example, 58 bytes that are pretty darn likely to work:

```
SELECT TOP 100'Have a great Christmas'FROM sys.all_objects
```

Comment: All Brilliant!!

Answer (score 4):

## SQL Server 2016, <s>54</s> 53 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to [@Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).*

```
select top 100'Have a great Christmas'from spt_values
```

Works in my instance of SQL Server 2016.

`spt_values` may be replaced with any system view/table of at least 100 rows.

Inspired by this [tips answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172557/55372).

Comment: Very good! I should have gone with a bigger number :D

Comment: Can the space at `Christmas'from` be removed?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, yes, it seems so. Thanks!